# Computation of functional determinant of Lorenz gauge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge, functional-determinants

In the Peskin and Schroeder's book P295, there is a derivation I don't quiet understand.

In Lorenz gauge we have $$G(A^\alpha)=\partial^\mu A_\mu+(1/e)\partial^2 \alpha.$$ Then it says that we could get that $$\det(\delta G(A^\alpha)/\delta\alpha)=\det(\partial^2 /e).$$

My question is that how you obtain the second equation dierctly from the first equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to consider the Fourier transform
$$G(A^\alpha)=ik^\mu A_\mu-{k^2\over e}\alpha$$
The functionnal derivative yields
$${\delta G\over\delta\alpha}=-{k^2\over e}$$
so the determinant is
$$\det{\delta G\over\delta\alpha}=-{1\over e}\det k^2$$
that you can formally write
$$\det{\delta G\over\delta\alpha}={1\over e}\det \partial^2$$